# Disable auto escape in python

Tags: python

When performing a simple open-read command from a web based document which contains text that is already escaped, python adds `\` to the escape `\`:

```
href=\"http:\/\/
into
href=\\"http:\\/\\/
```

How do I disable this behavior?

#### UPDATE

Can be replicated with for example

```
a= 'href=\"http:\/\/'
```

or in my case

I simply did a open() then a read with mechanize.

So how do I tell python that the string is already escaped?

Comment: How do you see this - e.g. python code (basically python does not do this incorrectly - however the commands are not doing what you expect so we need to see the commands you use)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python is not changing anything. Look at the below:

```
>>> a= 'href=\"http:\/\/'
>>> a
'href="http:\\/\\/' # the str() method is called
>>> repr(a)
'\'href="http:\\\\/\\\\/\'' # repr() is meant to be how the object can be "read" back, or provide detailed information
>>> str(a)
'href="http:\\/\\/' # see first example
>>> print a
href="http:\/\/ # any conversion etc... is not performed, ie, you get your original string printed
```

Answer (score 1):

Python just does so for displaying purposes, and ony if you are fooling around in the interpreter.

In other words, it only does so if using `repr()` explicitly or implicitly.

It shows them, but it doesn't use them. They are not really there.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape forward slashes. Thus your input string is at fault. The double backslash in the python output is just the way the Interpreter represents a single backslash, if you print it "\\" shows up as one.